# html readonly attribute on input not changes first time in IE 11

Tags: html, reactjs, internet-explorer, input

I am updating the readonly property of the output on component's state change which happening in onFocus handler. The code works fine on Chrome and Firefox but on IE 11 you must click two times and then start to write something to input. How to fix it?
I made an example of my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/94j1j8jnwy

UPD: found almost similar issue [here](http://tracker.zkoss.org/browse/ZK-3237)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer although it looks like a hack and it is a bit dirty.
The solution is to loose focus from input and return it again. Also I used ref to input and setTimeout.

```
handleOnFocus() {
  console.log('focused!');
  if (this.state.readOnly) {
    this.setState({ readOnly: false }, () => {
      this.input.blur();
      setTimeout(() => this.input.focus(), 0);
    });
  }
}

// ...

<input 
  ...
  ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }} />
```

Full code is on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vrlj9px63)